# Can't find documentation for strtok_s()

Tags: c, strtok

What exactly is each argument passed to it, what does it return?

How exactly is it better than the regular `strtok`?

Please give me the most simplified and basic explanation possible.

Comment: Note: `strtok_s()` is a Microsoft extension http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx.

Comment: @pmg actually `strtok_s()` was added as an [optional library addition in C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: Many thanks, found it in the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

This is detailed in `Appendix K (bounds checking interfaces)` of the `ISO C11` standard. This optional part of the standard provides "safer" <sup>(a)</sup> versions of already existing functionality provided in the core part of the standard.

The prototype is:

```
char *strtok_s (
    char * restrict        s1,
    rsize_t * restrict     s1max,
    const char * restrict  s2,
    char ** restrict       ptr);
```

The runtime constraints that are checked as part of the safety features are:

- The pointers `s1max`, `s2`, and `ptr` must all be non-null.
- If `s1` is a null pointer, then `*ptr` must not be.
- The value of `*s1max` must be less than or equal to `RSIZE_MAX`.
- The end of the token found must occur within the first `*s1max` characters of `s1` for the first call
- The end of the token found must occur within the first `*s1max` characters of where searching resumes on subsequent calls.

The safety aspect is that, if any of those constraints are violated, no indirection occurs on `s1` or `s2` and no value is stored via `ptr`.

Other than those extra checks, it pretty much works identically to the standard `strtok` function, returning tokens from `s1` separated by groups of delimiters found in `s2`. I think the use of `ptr` makes it thread-safe since it using a non-static state provided by the user <sup>(b)</sup>.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Quoted because most parts of the standard are *already* safe if you know how to use them properly :-)

---

<sup>(b)</sup> The one thing that's *still* missing is the ability to have empty tokens such as:

```
field1||||field5
```

Because `strtok_s` (and the original) treat `||||` as a *single* separator, we have to find other ways to do this `</rant>` :-)